# Поворот объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotation

Необходимо повернуть объект в юнити. В Inspector видно, что он повёрнут, но в показе камеры это не заметно, т.е. материал не поворачивается вместе с объектом. В коде я сначала присваиваю объекту материал, и только потом поворачиваю следующим кодом:

```
obj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90*k, 0);
```

где k - рандомное число от 0 до 3

Потом пробовал через:

```
obj.transform.Rotate(0, 90*k, 0);
```

но результат тот же

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил. Оказалось, что код рабочий, и надо лишь в объекте в Inspector открыть Static и убрать там галочку с компонента BatchingStatic. Всё заработало.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]